# Cookie Operations using Modsecurity Rules

Tags: apache, mod-security

Here, I'm trying to accomplish calling a Lua script from modsecurity rules.

There are 2 components:-

1.example.com (WAF)

2.test.com (Web Application)

test.com contains pages:-

```
index.php
protectedpage.php
```

If user accesses `http://example.com/protectedpage.php` the rule loads the lua script and writes data to lua_output.txt .

I have been stuck here for past 2 days trying several variations.

> Contents of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    LoadModule security3_module /home/testuser/spiderlabs/ModSecurity-apache/src/.libs/mod_security3.so
    <IfModule security3_module>
            modsecurity_rules 'SecRuleEngine On'
            modsecurity_rules 'SecRequestBodyAccess On'
            modsecurity_rules 'SecResponseBodyAccess On'
            modsecurity_rules_file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/include.conf"
            modsecurity_rules 'SecAuditLogFormat JSON'
    </IfModule>

    #Access to /getprotected 
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "^/getprotected.php$" "phase:2, t:none, t:normalisePath, t:lowercase, t:urlDecodeUni, chain, deny, log, id:1301"'
    modsecurity_rules 'SecRuleScript /etc/apache2/lua/checkaccess.lua \
    "id:400,Phase:2"'

    ProxyPass /getprotected.php !
    ProxyPass /getpassword.php !
    ProxyPass / http://test.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://test.com:8080/
```

> Contents of /etc/apache2/lua/checkaccess.lua

```
   #!/usr/bin/lua

    function main()
        local f = assert(io.open('/etc/apache2/lua/lua_output.txt','a'))
        f:write("--- Hello world ---\n")
    end
```

The Rule is executed. But the script is not. I'm not sure whether its chaining or not.
please Let me know how to fix this.
Thanks,

References so far:-
1. [ModSecurity Documentation](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29)

2. [Lua scripting blog 1](https://gryzli.info/2015/12/25/modsecurity-using-lua-scripts-with-secrulescript/)
3. [blog 2](https://www.htbridge.com/blog/patching-complex-web-vulnerabilities-using-modsecurity-waf.html#improper_access_control)

Comment: So the SecRule doesn't look right to me. In chain rules, the phase and ID needs to only be specified in the first rule. Also, since the rule is only checking the requested URI, it should be shifted to phase 1.

Comment: Yes i knew it.. But without Id in chained rule i use to get compilation errors which vanished once i used id...

Comment: If that is the case, please paste the error message you are getting. Also, I don't understand what is modsecurity_rules directive is. The ModSecurity SecRule directives should work if the module is loaded without needing any modsecurity_rules line.

Comment: Actually I'm using modsecurity version 3.0... so that's the new syntax ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lua script, why are you doing first a secrule then chain, you better call the script and get the var REQUEST_FILENAME and check it matches your pattern or add a Location/LocationMatch for the path and add the SecRuleScript inside.

The first rule is incomplete as it is a chain start that has no end as the next one is not a rule is a script call.